# Defining a property in haskel locally

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I have written this property check in haskell:

```
prop_XY (x,y) sud = ((!!) (rows (sud)) x) !! y
```

and i need to define this locally, any suggestions on how to do it as i am clueless how to do it?

**EDIT**

So this is the two prop functions i have, and i need to define the second one locally.

```
-- Check update function
prop_update (x,y) sud n = prop_XY (x',y') (update sud (x',y') n) == n 
                          where x' = x `mod` 9 
                                y' = y `mod` 9

-- helper to find specific value 
prop_XY (x,y) sud = ((!!) (rows (sud)) x) !! y
```

Comment: What do you mean by "locally"?  So the definition does not escape the scope of a function?  Use `let` or `where` as in the current answer.  So the definition does not escape the module? Use an explicit export list at the top `module Foo (... symbols not including prop_XY ...) where`.  Something else?

Comment: This is what our instructor said to us, "please define prop_XY locally instead since you only use it in prop_update." not really sure what he means by it @ThomasM.DuBuisson

Comment: @TimoCengiz btw, `(!!)` is discouraged... not only will it potentially have to go through the entire list, but see also: https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_functions

Comment: @TimoCengiz The implication of that sentence is it should be local to the `prop_update` function.  I would use either `let` or, probably better, `where` as shown by @CamilStaps.

Comment: But i dont understand what "myGlobalFunction" is in my case? If you check the latest of my questions here in stack you can see the the whole code for this assignment. @ThomasM.DuBuisson

Comment: @TimoCengiz Do you understand `where`?  Do you now understand "local" to mean syntactically in scope only of `prop_update`?  If so, you should be able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you can use a `where` clause:

```
prop_update ... = ... prop_XY (x,y) ...
  where
    prop_XY (x,y) sud = ((!!) (rows (sud)) x) !! y
```

See http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#where for more information.

Comment: Totally missed this, but what is myGlobalFunction in my case thats what i dont get. I got the comment that i should do: " define  prop_XY locally instead since you only use it in prop_update "

Comment: I am a beginner at this so please have a look at the edit. Thank you